# Excel macro: Replace enitre cell contents; replace 1 but not 10, 11, 21 etc

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, find-and-replace

I need to replace a large amount of numbers with words in an Excel spreadsheet.
Eg:

```
1 = hello
12 = goodbye
4 = cat
```

etc. I can do it with the standard search and replace, but I have a large list to work through (about 240 number/word combos), so i figured I would use a macro.

I have this:

```vba
Sub findreplacer()
For Each mycell In Range("A1:A1000")
mycell.Replace What:="1", Replacement:="hello"
mycell.Replace What:="12", Replacement:="goodbye"
mycell.Replace What:="4", Replacement:="cat"
Next

End Sub
```

But it replaces the 1 in 12 so the cell reads hello2 instead of goodbye.
How can I make it just affect cells that only contain the specific number, the way 'match entire cell contents' works?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the order is fine, so long as every value in the sheet is going to be replaced. If your sheet contained 11 though that wasn't going to be replaced then changing the order will still replace it with hello1.
To use match entire cell specify

```
,LookAt:=xlWhole
```

as another parameter to the Replace method.
Replace is a valid method on a Range so your For loop is not necessary.
You can instead specify

```
Range("A1:A1000").Replace What:="12", Replacement:="goodbye", LookAt:=xlWhole  
Range("A1:A1000").Replace What:="4", Replacement:="cat", LookAt:=xlWhole
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's a better solution, but what that says in my mind is put them in reverse order. For instance:

```vba
Sub findreplacer()
For Each mycell In Range("A1:A1000")
mycell.Replace What:="12", Replacement:="goodbye"
mycell.Replace What:="4", Replacement:="cat"
mycell.Replace What:="1", Replacement:="hello"
Next

End Sub
```

In that case, 12 would be replaced by "goodbye" first, and when the line that replaces 1 with "hello" comes around, it would have already changed.

Again, there's probably a better solution, but I think this would work for a quick fix in the parameters you described.

Comment: Great, not particularly elegant, but it works just fine, Thanks